# Python pygame converting drawing to an image

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game that is using a grid. But I have to calculate that grid every frame. Can I save the grid? So I just have to blit the grid on the screen?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('grid')
running = True
def drawgrid():
    for x in range(0, width, 40):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, 0, 2, height))
    for y in range(0, height, 40):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, y, width, 2))
while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,120))
    drawgrid()
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running == False
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a surface with the same size as the display and the background color:

```py
grid_surf = pygame.Surface((width, height))
grid_surf.fill((255,255,120))
```

Draw the grid to this surface:

```py
def drawgrid(surf):
    for x in range(0, width, 40):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (0, 0, 0), (x, 0, 2, height))
    for y in range(0, height, 40):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (0, 0, 0), (0, y, width, 2))
```

```py
drawgrid(grid_surf)
```

And blit the surface in the main application loop instead of drawing the grid and background:

```py
screen.blit(grid_surf, (0, 0))
```

Example code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('grid')

def drawgrid(surf):
    for x in range(0, width, 40):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (0, 0, 0), (x, 0, 2, height))
    for y in range(0, height, 40):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (0, 0, 0), (0, y, width, 2))

grid_surf = pygame.Surface((width, height))
grid_surf.fill((255,255,120))
drawgrid(grid_surf)

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(grid_surf, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running == False
            pygame.quit()
```